# @synthesize hides file header?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

My project works fine on simulator but wouldn't build on real device after adding:

```
@synthesize extraView=_extraView;
```

It seems that this line somehow hides file header. Tried "Clean" - no change. 
I've used @property and @synthesize many times before and haven't seen anything like this.
I'm planning to rewrite extraView handling but I'm asking just out of curiosity if someone has experienced similar error.

Platform:

```
XCode 4.0.1
4.2.1 Ipad
```

File header:

```
//
//  MediaBook.h
//  Dolphin
//
//  Created by Handymood on 11-5-22.
//  Copyright 2011 __Hanydmood__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SinglePage.h"
#import "LayerInfo.h"
#import "MediaBookXMLParser.h"
#import "GlobalSet.h"
#import "UIComponentBase.h"
#import "IndexPageInfo.h"
#import "IndexPage.h"
#import "TopBar.h"
#import "BottomBar.h"
#import "DolphinUIWebLayer.h"
#import "MediaBookBase.h"
#import "ColorUtil.h"
#import "DolphinUICategory.h"
#import "UICategoryUnit.h"
#import "ImageInfoBox.h"
#import "Gallery.h"
#import "Calendar.h"

@class SinglePage;
@class LayerInfo;
@class MediaBookXMLParser;
@class GlobalSet;
@class UIComponentBase;
@class IndexPageInfo;
@class IndexPage;
@class TopBar;
@class BottomBar;
@class DolphinUIWebLayer;
@class MediaBookBase;
@class ColorUtil;
@class DolphinUICategory;
@class UICategoryUnit;

@interface MediaBook : MediaBookBase <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIImageLayer *backGroundImage;
    UIView           *bgView;
    BottomBar     *bottomBar;
    DolphinUIWebLayer  *webLayer;
    DolphinUICategory    *categoryLayer;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    UIInterfaceOrientation    preOrientation;

    NSTimer *objQueMagTimer;

    float previous_scroll_pos;

    BOOL bar_status_hidden;
    float top_bar_ori_y;
    float bottom_bar_ori_y;

    BOOL scroll_block_signal;

    int screen_direction;//0:vertical 1:horizontal

    BOOL webLayerOn;
    BOOL categoryOn;

    BOOL changingExtraView;
}

@property UIInterfaceOrientation    preOrientation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *extraView;

-(void) initWithGlobalSet:(GlobalSet *) inGlobalSet;
-(void) initBook:(NSString *)configXmlAdd curOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

-(void) initBookContent;

-(void) notificationSelector:(NSNotification *) notification;

-(void) statusBarAnimationTrigger;

-(void) layoutAdjustWithOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
                                orientaionType:(NSString *) inOrientationType;

-(void) closeCategoryLayer;

-(void) reset;

-(void) showExtraView:(NSString *)name;
-(void) hideExtraView;

@end
```

Screenshot of build errors:

[image]

I've used @property and @synthesize many times before and haven't seen any similar.

Comment: are those undeclared vars declared in the superclass? (`MediaBookBase`) What about `_extraView`, is it declared in the superview or you use generated ivars?

Comment: You are importing a class (#import), then saying you will import that later (@class). That seems unnecessary. I also fail to see where fit_with_screen is defined. If you tried to fix a circular dependency and failed, Xcode won't notice the failed imports. Maybe you should move those #imports to the .m file, but there are too many of them, if you really need that many you have a mess on your hands, that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - the problem with the mess is that we are using handymood.com app template for this project and these imports & @class declarations came with the package :) Though I wasn't sure if they are really necessary.

Comment: Thanks to mja comment, I added UIView *_extraView; to my interface declaration - it solves the problem. But I'm still not sure how it was related with @synthesize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following to interface declaration solved the problem:

```
UIView *_extraView;
```

Thanks to mja for the tip.